# Problem to capture ChromeHeadless launcher Using Puppeteer

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, puppeteer, docker-machine, google-chrome-headless, karma-chrome-launcher

can someone help me in this issue?

I am getting the '[launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.' when the pipeline (Jenkins) is trying to exec the tests with karma (Puppeteer using ChromeHeadless)

We have as demmand of the client to change the launcher from Phantomjs to ChromeHeadless;

We've tried a lot of things and nothing works until now and i have no idea how to solve it.

some informations about the project configurations:

We use angular 7, karma dependencies and puppeteer as follow :

```
package.json
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "my",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test -c karma.conf.js -cc --browsers MyChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.15",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "angl-spawebbgrl": "^6.2.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.4",
    "angular2-tinymce": "2.1.2",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "1.9.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^6.5.0",
    "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.12.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "8.10.59",
    "bower-art-resolver": "^2.0.10",
    "chai": "4.2.0",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-sinon": "1.0.5",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "1.23.1",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.6.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.5",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
  }
}
```

Our karma configuration:

```
karma.conf.js

module.exports = function (config) {

  const process = require('process');
  process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files:[
      'src/test.ts'
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      dir: 'coverage',
      'report-config':  { html: { subdir: 'html'} }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'coverage'], 
    port: 9876,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: false,
    singleRun: true,
    browsers: ['MyChromeHeadless'], 
    customLaunchers: {
    MyChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--proxy-auto-detect'
        ]
      }
    }
  });
};
```

This error occurs when jenkins try to exec the tests, but locally runs everything ok. This problem is specific of the pipeline that is running over a linux machine;

Has someone to help me to get '[launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.' fixed?

Any advice will be welcome. Tkx!

Answer (score 0):

Just checking, but are you sure a valid version of Chrome is installed on the pipelined machine, and that the path is set so the launcher can find it?

It sounds like the laucher is timing out just trying to fire up HC, and the most obvious issue whould be it not being able to find a version to run.

Comment: When the pipeline machine gives npm install, the puppeteer dependencie take the Chromium donwload and with this line in my karma.conf 

``` process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath(); ``` 

We set the right path for the launcher get the chrome, something like: /opt/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-706915/chrome-linux/chrome

But still no happness.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira could you pls help me on my [ISSUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73287910/how-to-understand-and-resolve-jenkin-job-failure-angular-13-app) ?  I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0):

i discovered how to solve this issue.

The client has a proxy-blocker to manage the networking configurations. So i provided the proxy as server in the customLauncher flag and works perfectly, but only in the pipeline, locally  the tests stopped. but it's just take off the proxy that runs locally.

Before: This way the tests runs locally, but do not works in the jenkins pipeline (npm run test)

```
browsers: ['MyChromeHeadless'], 
    customLaunchers: {
    MyChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--proxy-auto-detect'
        ]
      }
    }
```

After: This way the tests runs in the pipeline, but do not works locally cuz i'm not under the client networking with access to the proxy provied

```
browsers: ['MyChromeHeadless'], 
    customLaunchers: {
    MyChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
          '--proxy-server=http://proxy.your.company'
        ]
      }
    }
```